# Encode and Decode byte[] into string in java?

Tags: base64, decode, encode

How to encode byte array into string and the same decode the encodedstring into byte array? Mostly i want to save the encoded string into server and decoded the same into byte array for image loading from server.

Answer (score 0):

If programmers want to encode and decode byte[] in java. Here is the sample code for your knowledge. Use this below code

Encode Byte array into String

```
String strByteValue = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayValue, Base64.URL_SAFE);
```

Decode String into Byte[]

```
byte decodedString[] = Base64.decode(strByteValue , Base64.URL_SAFE);
```